# HTML files created by Notepad (Microsoft free version) will not display images in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, notepad

I am helping fellow student through beginning HTML.  The html files she creates in Notepad (Microsoft free version in OS), when viewed in IE do not display images (local files, local images).  Code has been successfully validated in w3 validator, we both checked over image and file path multiple times, image names, extensions, everything is correct.

Other browsers will display images (Safari, Opera, Firefox) but IE will not. Neither I nor they could get the images to display in IE from files she created. When I copy the *same exact code* into new document, delete old doc rename new with old name, all browsers including IE displays the images, but no code has changed. Similarly, my identically constructed pages (this part was all copied directly from textbook as an exercise) my files work perfectly.

I am starting to think her Notepad installation may be buggy or corrupted.  Anyone ever experience anything similar to this with Notepad?  Anyone know of a good resource for helping a newer than newbie reinstall Notepad - or do you have other recommendations for text editor instead? Thanks!

For those who don't believe me, this is the non-working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="CIW, XHTML 1.0, Habitat for Humanity"/>
<meta name="Description" content="Simple XHTML page for Habitat site"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syb/syb.css" title="stylesheet"/>

<title>Habitat for Humanity International Summer Youth Blitz Program</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
<blockquote>
<img src="syb/SYBcollage2.png" alt="Join a summer build!"/>
</blockquote>

<h1>Join a Summer Build for Teen-agers</h1>

<blockquote>
<p>
The <em>Summer Youth Blitz</em> is a unique service experience for a diverse group of youth,
<br/>ages 16 to 18, from high schools and youth organizations around the United States. <br/>
During this program, 15 to 20 youth participants and adult leaders <br/>"blitz build" an entire
Habitat house in two weeks.
</p>
</blockquote>

<hr width="800" size="5" align="center"/>

<blockquote>
<div align="center">For more information, contact us at (800) 422-4828, ext.
2220.</div>
</blockquote>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the working code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="CIW, XHTML 1.0, Habitat for Humanity"/>
<meta name="Description" content="Simple XHTML page for Habitat site"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syb/syb.css" title="stylesheet"/>

<title>Habitat for Humanity International Summer Youth Blitz Program</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
<blockquote>
<img src="syb/SYBcollage2.png" alt="Join a summer build!"/>
</blockquote>

<h1>Join a Summer Build for Teen-agers</h1>

<blockquote>
<p>
The <em>Summer Youth Blitz</em> is a unique service experience for a diverse group of youth,
<br/>ages 16 to 18, from high schools and youth organizations around the United States. <br/>
During this program, 15 to 20 youth participants and adult leaders <br/>"blitz build" an entire
Habitat house in two weeks.
</p>
</blockquote>

<hr width="800" size="5" align="center"/>

<blockquote>
<div align="center">For more information, contact us at (800) 422-4828, ext.
2220.</div>
</blockquote>

</body>
</html>
```

Not sure how to convince the thumbs downers it's the same code. I just tried it again to make sure I'm not crazy.
Copied/Pasted her CODE into a new document - every single character same-same.  The document SHE created and zipped to me doesn't display images.  The document I created with exactly duplicated code does display images fine, but the issue only occurs in IE. I appreciate the fact that you all know more than I, that's why I'm here, but to vote it down because you're incredulous, what gives?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Notepad. Tell us what version of IE you are using, and show us some of your code--just the top 20 or 30 lines will be enough.

Comment: Recommendations? free version of Visual Studio, Eclipse, Notepad++...pretty much ANYTHING but Notepad.

Comment: A corrupted Notepad doesn't sound very likely. How about archiving the working and non-working versions of the files and sharing them?

Comment: I use [aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) for all my web development. Rather fantastic IMO. For something small and simple, Notepad++ is good, though.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with? what types of image file are you trying to display? (gif? jpg? png? svg? etc..?)

Comment: Copy the main HTML into a pastie.org, and let's have the URL here `:)`

Answer (score 2):

make sure your file is saved as htm or HTML extension, sometimes in windows extensions are hidden so you may also need to check in the folder options that the files you are saving has some_page.htm or some_page.html and not some_page.htm.txt ....

as far as html is concerned.

the HTML should be well written and for images should be in body tag like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the page
</title>
</head>
<body>

<img height="175" align="center"src="images/Picture_5.png" border="0">
</body>
</html>
```

make sure the paths are correctly written like in above example the path is relative and images are stored in images folder which is at the same location where html file is.

Comment: To reiterate:

When I copy the same exact code into new document, delete old doc rename new with old name, all browsers including IE displays the images, but no code has changed.

**This behavior is rather strange, don't you think? It's NOT a coding error.

and

Code has been successfully validated in w3 validator, we both checked over image and file path multiple times, image names, extensions, everything is correct.

Comment: make sure you are opening the right file...

Comment: This has been closed, so I can't add an answer, but: it's probably the image path. To test this, replace the `src` parameter with an image from somewhere on the web (`src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png"`). If the problem disappears, it's got nothing to do with the editor.